# Why are Custom object Name Field and date fields (Deterministic Encryption) not allowed to be encrypted?

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

I read a lot of documentation regarding Shield Platform Encryption and I can't find any statement in regards to why some of these custom Object Name Field and date fields (Deterministic Encryption) are not allowed. Could you please advise me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why some of these custom Object Name Field and date fields (Deterministic Encryption) are not allowed.

The short answer is:

```
For Name - it is not
For Standard Date fields - not supported
For custom Date fields - supported, probabilistic only
```

One of the questions at the recent `True to the Core` Dreamforce session explicitly asked when fields of type Date (standard fields) and Picklist could be encrypted. The answer at the time was "we'll get back to you"

Under the covers, date fields show up a lot in filters for listviews and reports. Because encrypted fields can't be sorted, this would impose a burden on applications.  Hypothesizing, the same could be true for name fields (which also can be auto-number that throws in a new wrinkle).

I've also heard that these issues can be better addressed if encryption were done closer to the hardware (SAN level).

### Possible Workaround for the Name field

Start with using an autonumber field for the Name field and then use an external ID unique field for what you were putting in the Name field. The External Id field can be encrypted.

### Possible workaround for standard Date fields

Use a trigger or automation to move (i.e. delete and copy) the value from a standard date field like `Contact.Birthdate` to an encrypted custom date field like `Contact.Birthdate_PII__c`

Comment: @TejeshP - I updated my answer to be more complete

Comment: @ Cropredy, Thanks for your answered

Comment: @ Cropredy, For custom Date fields - supported(Probabilistic Encryption) but Deterministic Encryption is not supported. do we have a chance date field Deterministic Encryption?

Comment: Available Fields and Other Data
Deterministic encryption is available for custom URL, email, phone, text, and text area field types. It isn’t available for the following types of data:

Custom date, date/time, long text area, rich text area, or description field types
Chatter
Files and attachment

Comment: @TejeshP - thanks for correcting me ... you get what you get with Shield Encryption; if you wanted to deterministically encrypt a Date - move it to a Text field of length 10 and store as `yyyy-mm-dd`